# SSRS report - missing borders in detail rows under groups

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I want my report to have borders around all cells in all rows. In picture below you see that borders in detail rows under groups are missing. How to add them?

[image: Report design]

[image: Report row groups]

Comment: So you want to have a fully filled in grid like you would see in Excel?

Comment: @StevenWhite, Yes, I want to see all lines like in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to show all the borders with a few rearrangements.

The problem is that you can't split vertically merged row group header cells from outer groups, this works only once in the first outer group.

The rearrangements would be to delete the outer group columns, here from left to right (delete only columns, not groups!), then you should be able to create new rows and columns step by step and split cells if necessary, at some point you may need the "HideDuplicates" options, depending on the actual structure of your tablix or matrix.
If needed, play with the options to add group results, add/delete rows, columns and headers (deleting only the rows, not the groups).